# Expected value or positive integers

Tags: probability

> Show that if $\operatorname{Ran}(X)=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, then
>   $$\displaystyle E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq n). $$

I'm stuck how to start this, I can't figure out whether to work with geometric or poisson distrbutions.  If it's geometric, I've found the expected to be $\frac{1}{p}$.

Or if we look at the finite set $\displaystyle E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}.$

I think the right side should be equal to $\displaystyle 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X < n)$.

Comment: Your first equation is confusing. The index of the sum is $i$ but the terms are indexed by $n$. You have to choose one and be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 
$$
E[X] = \sum_{n= 1}^\infty n P(X=n) = \sum_{n= 1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n P(X=n)
$$
and change the order of summation. Hint: $k\le n$ is equivalent to $n\ge k$.

Comment: Continuing: = $\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X=n)$, but  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X=n)=1$ for any pmf, then have$ \sum_{k=1}^n 1$  However isn't this equal to n, equal to $P(X \leq n) $?

Comment: @Sunhwa, no. You lack basic understanding on changing the order of summation. If you have summation over $n$ inside, you cannot have this outside.

Comment: @Sunhwa, this is what written in my post. Nothing changed... I've added a hint.

Comment: Thank you very much!  You were actually very helpful :D I never learned series very well ... I think I've got it now:  

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n P(X=n) $

$= \sum_{n,k} [1\leq k \leq n][1 \leq n \leq \infty] P(X=n)$

$= \sum_{n,k} [1 \leq k \leq n \leq \infty] P(X=n) $

$= \sum_{k,n} [1 \leq k \leq \infty][k \leq n \leq \infty] P(X=n)$

$= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} P(X=n)$

$= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq n)$

Comment: @Sunhwa, you use Iverson's notation, wow. Anyway, you're welcome.